# Putting frame only around equation using mdframed package

Tags: mdframed

I am in the process of finalizing the notebook text, and I am into framing equations and figures.  For this I am testing `mdframed` package, which produces nice frames.  However, I don't know how to frame only equations, without framing equation numbers.  Is that possible in `mdframed`?

Comment: For framing equations you should have a look at the `empheq` package.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To supplement the answer of Harish Kumar, the packages `empheq` and `tcolorbox` can by used in symbiosis. `empheq` allows to specify any **box** to mark the given equations. For the **box** you may insert any `tcolorbox` which behaves like `fbox`. Typically, such boxes are based on the `\tcbox` macro (like `\tcbhighmath` in the answer of Harish Kumar).

I think, the following example demonstrates what you can do. The singleline equation is boxed with `\tcbhighmath` directly, the multiline equations (`align`) are boxed using `empheq` in conjunction with `\tcbhighmath` and some other `\tcbox`-based examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
  colframe=red!60!black,colback=yellow!50!white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt,
  drop fuzzy shadow}}

\newtcbox{\otherbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,
  enhanced,frame hidden,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=green!10!white,
  bottom color=green!10!white,middle color=green!50!yellow},
  fuzzy halo=1pt with green,#1}

\newtcbox{\picturebox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,
  enhanced,watermark graphics=example-grid-100x100bp.jpg,% from package mwe
  colback=white,frame hidden,boxrule=0pt,arc=10pt,
  watermark stretch=1.00,watermark opacity=0.4,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{E = mc^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box={\tcbhighmath[colback=blue!20!white]}]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box={\tcbhighmath[watermark text=?!,watermark color=yellow!90!red]}]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\otherbox]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\picturebox]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,theorems]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
  colframe=red!60!black,colback=white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt}}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.8, .7, 1}
\newcommand*\mybluebox[1]{%
\colorbox{myblue}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\begin{document}
Using \verb|tcolorbox|:
\begin{equation}
\tcbhighmath{E = mc^2}
\end{equation}
Using \verb|Aboxed| from \verb|mathtools|:
\begin{align}
\Aboxed{E &= mc^2}
\end{align}
Using \verb|empheq| (taken from manual):
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}
Adding some color (taken from manual):
\begin{empheq}[box=\mybluebox]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting stuff.  Since you are obviously knowledgeable in this area, which package in your opinion is the best for my use - I am writing a book, and I need frames around formulas, pictures, occasionally text etc.

Comment: @Pygmalion My first like is `tcolorbox` as it is more fancier. But don't ignore `empheq` too as it has some good features.

Comment: tcolorbox looks tempting, but I have just found out it does not support frames around align environment (multiple equations within frame without equation numbers)

Comment: @Pygmalion That is what I meant in my previous comment. But `empheq` saves you there :)

Comment: Indeed, but are you sure that empheq can create exactly the same frame style as tcolorbox?

Comment: @pygmalion I am skeptical about that. tcolorbox can get way more fancier than empheq.

Comment: @Pygmalion You can combine `empheq` and `tcolorbox` to frame multiple equations without equation numbers :-) I added an answer to show how to do this.