# Small box just surrounding the equation, not the whole line?

Tags: math-mode, framed

The following example makes a huge box that's the full width of the text, including the equation number:

```
\begin{framed}
\begin{equation}
  x=y
\end{equation}  
\end{framed}
```

Is there a way to get a box just around the equation itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best is to use `boxed` from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Using \verb|boxed| from \verb|amsmath|:
\begin{equation}
\boxed{x=y}
\end{equation}
Using \verb|fbox|:
\begin{equation}
\fbox{$x=y$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `align` and friends from `amsamth`, you are better off with `Aboxed` from `mathtools` package. A relevant and useful reference will be [This question and its answers.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134984/11232)