# Error with \framebox inside $$

Tags: errors

I'm new to LaTeX, and I'm having an issue with using `\framebox` inside an equation (denoted with `$$` signs at the beginning and the end).

The text that I'm trying to box is the following:

```
1.5 \times 10^{- 5} \; Pa
```

However, once I put a `\framebox` around it, like so:

```
\framebox{1.5 \times 10^{- 5} \; Pa}
```

I get the following error:

> ./assignment1.tex:85: Missing $ inserted.

...where 85 points to the line where I put in the `\framebox`. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Inside the argument to the `\framebox`, the outer math environment is lost.  You must place the argument itself inside math delimiters (single `$`)

Comment: If you want to keep the expression in displayed mode, you can load `amsmath` and use `\boxed`, as the following example shows: `\[
\boxed{1.5 \times 10^{- 5} \; Pa}
\]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`boxed` will not span an equation if it encloses an alignment point i.e., `&` . In such cases you can use `Aboxed` from `mathtools`. See the example below for illustration. Further, to typeset units, better use `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \framebox{$1.5 \times 10^{- 5}\si{\pascal}$}
  \begin{align}
    &\boxed{1.5 \times 10^{- 5}\si{\pascal}}\\
    \Aboxed{\text{Pressure} &=1.5 \times 10^{- 5}\si{\pascal}}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A useful read will be [this Q and its A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134984/putting-frame-only-around-equation-using-mdframed-package/135000#135000)

Comment: You wrote "`\boxed` will not span an entire equation" and that is not exactly true. `\boxed` will span an entire equation unless the box should cross an alignment point.

Comment: No problem :-) I'll delete this comment, and the previous one, shortly.

Answer (score 7):

Package `amsmath` provides a command, namely `\boxed`, to generate boxed math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\boxed{E = mc^2}\]

$\boxed{E =mc^2}$
\end{document}
```

BTW, do *NOT* use `$$`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/38350) for details.