# Include a graphics but without modifying the layout (i.e. add an image behind text)

Tags: graphics, border, definition

I'd like to define a command `\mark` that would add an image `mark.png` :

- on the same vertical coordinate than the current text
- at 1cm from left border
- without modifying the layout, i.e. if I remove this command, the text shouldn't move, the pages should have the same layout

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\mark{\includegraphics{test.png}}
\begin{document}
Hello world
$$x^2+1$$
\mark Hello world
\end{document}
```

Without:

[image]

Expected behaviour:

[image]

Currently bad output:

[image]

Comment: Maybe try to place your image in the `\marginpar{}`?

Comment: You should really not use `$$`

Comment: @samcarter better `\marginnote` (better placement).

Comment: @Skillmon OK, I'll reformulate to "something starting with `\margin`" :)

Comment: @Skillmon Do you want to answer?

Comment: @samcarter perhaps after lunch (if you didn't provide one until then).

Comment: @Basj and you shouldn't redefine `\mark`. Perhaps use `\newcommand\mymark{...}` instead.

Comment: See also the `tabto` package: `\tabto*{-1cm}X\tabto{\TabPrevPos}`

Comment: Try `\rlap{\includegraphics{path}}`, which will lap the image to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place your image in the margin, this ensures that it does not influence the layout of the main text.

To do this you could use `\marginpar{....}` or as @Skillmon suggested [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455795/include-a-graphics-but-without-modifying-the-layout-i-e-add-an-image-behind-te/455798#comment1146425_455795) `\marginnote{}` from the package of the same name for better placement.

Unrelated to the problem, but you should not use `$$...$$`, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for further information.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
Hello world
\[
    x^2+1
\]
\marginnote{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Since @samcarter allowed me to, here are some edits I'd use:

1. I'd put the macro into a `\begingroup`-`\endgroup` pair and keep the `\reversemarginpar` into that group, so that we don't affect other macros using it.
2. I'd put the `\includegraphics` into an `\rlap` so that it doesn't matter how wide the image is.
3. I'd change the alignment of `\marginnote` put into the left margin locally.

Put into code:

```
\newcommand\mymark[2][]
  {%
     \begingroup
     \reversemarginpar
     \renewcommand*\raggedleftmarginnote{\raggedright}%
     \marginnote{\rlap{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
     \endgroup
  }
```

Now you can use `\mymark` as you'd do with `\includegraphics` but putting the image into the margin.

---

Note: Don't forget to place it inside equations, if you want proper alignment:

```
 \[ \mymark x^2 +1 \]
```

works, whereas

```
 \mymark \[x^2 +1 \]
```

would produce [a misalignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT0R4.png).

Comment: If the image is large (say, 10 cm), can it go behind the text, without modifying the text's position?

Comment: @Basj Yes, it is placed behind the text. It will cause an overfull box warning though.

Comment: Also, could you just add a mention to explain what the reverse does? (`\reversemarginpar`) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Basj Per default margin notes go to the outer margin, but because you want them on the left site, you have to reverse this.

Comment: Thanks again @samcarter! Last detail: with `\documentclass{article}`, it does not go so close to the left border. How to position the image at 1cm of the left paper border, without modifying the borders of the document (this would modify the whole layout)?

Comment: @Basj You can adjust these spaces with the geometry package where you can set `marginparwidth` and `marginparsep`

Comment: @samcarter I'd put the `\reversemarginpar` grouped into the definition of a macro (say `\mymark`), also putting a `\rlap` around the `\includegraphics` might be a good idea.

Comment: @samcarter A little last glitch: with [this code](https://pastebin.com/mcn7u5k5), the graphic is well aligned on the text lines, but it's not well aligned (vertically) with equations with `\mark \[ ... \]`: https://imgur.com/a/S7t9cdm

Comment: @Basj You are using your `\mark` (which you should rename to something not already defined by latex) before the equation, thus it is part of the previous line and positioned correctly. If you want it to be aligned with the equations, use it there.

Comment: @Basj See this related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198871/alignment-margin-note-with-equation-in-pages

Comment: @samcarter Not sure it applies here, the linked question uses `empheq` and `tcolorbox`, etc. How would you do it in the case here? I didn't find how to adapt the other question to this case here.

Comment: @Basj With the link to the other question I just wanted to show that if you want to annotate an equation, then the margin note should be placed there and not before the equation.

Comment: @Basj Don't use `\mark`  :)

Comment: Why @samcarter? Is it a reserved word? I tried `\mark` but it didn't do anything special ;)

Comment: @Basj Because the command is already defined. If you would use `\newcommand` you would get an error. With your forced overwriting it can lead to problems, for example with headers.

Comment: @samcarter What does `\mark` do? Googling `latex mark` didn't really help ;)

Comment: @Basj It is used internally by tex for storing marks

Comment: @Basj My personal opinion: Don't overwrite commands you don't know what they are doing, because you will have no idea where to look for potential problems and if problems are noticed at some point debugging such problems is a nightmare.