# beamer box around equations

Tags: beamer, graphics

[image]

How can I make a fancy box around equations like the one in the left?
I tried many time on my own but nothing satisfactory obtained!

Comment: Just start with a block: `\begin{block}{} equation here \end{block}`. Then you can add some block styles.

Answer (score 11):

Here are some options with `empheq` and `tcolorbox` adopting code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135152/11232).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
  colframe=red!60!black,colback=yellow!50!white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt,
  }}

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,
  enhanced,frame hidden,boxrule=0pt,interior style={top color=green!10!white,
  bottom color=green!10!white,middle color=green!50!yellow},
  fuzzy halo=1pt with green,drop large lifted shadow,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box={\tcbhighmath[colback=blue!20!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,toprule=0pt,drop large lifted shadow]}]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot find `drop large lifted shadow` in the documentation of `tcolorbox`. Do you use a development version or is it just undocumented?

Comment: @HenriMenke It is there in documentation, page 155, of `tcolorbox` version 3.36 (9-1-2015)

Comment: Ah, I see. Then texdoc.net is not up-to-date.

Comment: @HenriMenke I tried to implement your codes but I got an error message: "File 'tcolorbox.sty' not found". I found it by search and then I got another error message: "I can't find file tcbskins.code.tex". I also found this file by search but I do not know what should I do. Do you know how to solve this issues?

Answer (score 5):

This should be a starting point.  I used `tcolorbox` for the fancy equation box.  The font is `biolinum`.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{sky blue}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=1em,rightskip=1em]{frametitle}%
      \insertshortauthor\hfill\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[sky blue]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{tcolorbox,mathtools,biolinum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,theorems}

\definecolor{sblue}{HTML}{0049A9}
\definecolor{scyan}{HTML}{CBEAFC}
\definecolor{sred}{HTML}{B5595C}
\definecolor{sgreen}{HTML}{609B57}
\definecolor{spink}{HTML}{FFB0FF}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=sblue,bg=scyan}

\newcommand\markit[1]{\textcolor{sblue}{#1}}
\newtcolorbox{fancyeqbox}[1][]{
  enhanced,drop fuzzy midday shadow,
  boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt,boxsep=0pt,
  left=.5em,right=.5em,top=1ex,bottom=1ex,
  colback=white,#1
}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\title{Controllo di Processo e dei Sistemi di Produzione -- A.a.\ 2009/09}
\author{\textcopyright\ 2009 by A.\ Bemporad}

\begin{frame}{Receding horizon philosophy}
  \begin{columns}[totalwidth=\linewidth]
    \column{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \underline{At time $t$:} solve and \markit{optimal control}
      problem over a finite future horizon of \markit{$N$} steps:
      \begin{fancyeqbox}[ams align*,width=\linewidth+.7cm,enlarge left by=-.7cm]
        \min_{u_t,\ldots,u_{t+N-1}}
        &\left\{ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \| {\color{sred} y_{t+k} - r(t)} \|^ 2 + \right. \\
        &\quad\left. \rho \| {\color{sred} u_{t+k} - u_r(t)} \|^2 \right\} \\
        \text{s.t.}\quad
        & {\color{sblue} x_{t+k+1} = f(x_{t+k},u_{t+k})} \\
        & {\color{sblue} y_{t+k} = g(x_{t+k},u_{t+k})} \\
        & {\color{sgreen} u_{\mathrm{min}} \leq u_{t+k} \leq u_{\mathrm{max}}} \\
        & {\color{sgreen} y_{\mathrm{min}} \leq y_{t+k} \leq y_{\mathrm{max}}} \\
        & x_{t} = x(t), k=0,\ldots,N-1
      \end{fancyeqbox}
    \end{itemize}

    \column{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-golden-upright}
  \end{columns}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Only apply the firt optimal move \markit{$u^*(t)$}
  \item \underline{At time $t+1$:} \markit{Get new measurements},
    repeat the optimization. And so on\ldots
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{center}
    \colorbox{spink}{Advantage of repeated on-line optimization: \textcolor{red}{FEEDBACK!}}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]